# jquery not validating form using jquery validation plug in

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and having problems validating code with jquery.validate

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
"use strict";
    $("#addNewQuestForm").validate({
        rules: {
            questName: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            }
        },
        messages:{
            questName: {
                required: "Enter Quest Name",
                minlength: "Quest Name must be at least 2 characters long"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and here is my form

```
<form action='<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>' method="post" id="addNewQuestForm" name="addNewQuestForm">
        <fieldset>
        <td colspan="1"><label for="questName"> Quest Name </label> <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Quest Name" type="text" id="questName" name="questName" minlength="2" required> </td>
        <td colspan=4>  
        <button type="submit" name="action" id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-small" value='addNewQuest'> Add New Quest </button>  
        </td>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

It is not validating at all?

Any help would be amazing! Thanks
Chris

Comment: Please explain the error you are getting

Comment: @Christopher Jansen, Hi what error you are getting in the console

Comment: Hi there is no error at all.. it simply sends the form when there validation conditions are not met. I.e there is noting put into the input field... No warnings come up in the console etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have missed the jquery validation cdn to add it,

Here is your working code in fiddle

https://fiddle.jshell.net/jvk3/n3agckpg/1/

Comment: Thanks whoami I am using both 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

Comment: no still not working.... :(

seeing your code i actually removed the jquery cdn link.. to jquery and it started popping up a warning like it would if you have it as required using html 5. It also gave a number of console errors.. 

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.validate.js:15
    at jquery.validate.js:17

Comment: when i include both libraries I get no errors... it just does not validate ... 

when i include only the jquery-validate.js  then it throws the error Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at jquery.validate.js:15 at jquery.validate.js:17

see code at https://fiddle.jshell.net/jckvrsnk/9/

Comment: Hi @ChristopherJansen, you form open and close was wrong, so the jquery validation is not working, Here is updated working fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/jvk3/6xsv8j39/

Comment: you are a legend! I have wasted many hours on this! Thanks so much!!